# Does this method returns a url?

Tags: python, json, url, request, google-places-api

Sorry, I'm learning so forgive me if this is a stupid question.
I got this method (updated):

```
    def get_photo(self, photo_reference):
    print(self.photourl)
    print(photo_reference)
    resp = requests.get(
        url='{}{}'.format(self.photourl, photo_reference),
        params={'key': self.api_key}
    )
    try:
        return resp.json()
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid JSON')
```

I built the requests.get with [Google Places API - Place Photo](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/photos). 
In my `__init__(self):`

```
self.place_detail_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/'
self.ref = 'photo?maxwidth=200&photoreference='
self.photourl = self.place_detail_url + self.ref
```

I want to get photo from google place API but I tried and it returns None.
I wonder what the `get_photo` method returns and if it isnt a url. How can I encode it to a url?

Comment: Should you be returning something from `get_photo()`?..

Comment: That method has no `return` statement in it, so it will return the default of `None`. I suspect that you should be assigning the value returned by the `requests.get` call and returning that, which should be an object containing the photo data you want (it also contains other useful stuff).

Comment: Are you trying to download a picture? requests.get(url).content You'll need to group this with an open command to save the file: `with open(file, 'wb') as file: file.write(requests.get(url).content)`

Comment: I did make it return something by making `resp = requests.get(..)` then `return resp.json()`

Comment: What error are you getting? What are you trying to achieve? So far the question is "Does it return a URL" and the cod provided has no return statement but you say one exists. Please update

Comment: But when I try to put the `url` and `params` together on browser, it changes to a url link like this [https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-rQMt55zcfQE/V4zs3RoOyII/AAAAAAAAlbY/qFzRNW4Xnbk_y2CD0euV3KxNFzI9icrQQCLIB/s1600-w400/] so I think it wont be a json. That's why I try another way

Comment: If you changed the function to return something, then edit your post to show the updated code.

Comment: I updated the code. Please check

Comment: I think you are mixing and matching request methods. I suspect that maxwidth= and photoreference = should be part of your params argument. Or if you want to build the URL yourself you should add your API key to the existing URL and handle all the formatting yourself. Mixing and matching seems like a good way to have things go wrong. Requests also has support for status codes. After your get request do a `print(resp.status_code)` If Google doesn't like your request it'll give you an error code

Comment: It prints status 200

Comment: Then Google says your request was good and they provided the answer. Are you sure you are expecting a json response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer, `resp` is a object and according to HTTP status 200, my URL is good. So I just need to do `return resp.url` to get the right URL link. It's a small problem but I made it big. Sorry and thank you to all your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this (Based on your seemingly preferred approach above of building the URL yourself):

```
def get_photo(self, photo_reference):
    request_url = (self.place_detail_url + self.ref + photo_reference + '&key=' + self.api_key)
    output_file = (/path/to/image/here/file.png)
    with open(output_file, 'wb') as output:
        output.write(requests.get(request_url).content)
```

Comment: Actually I want it to return a string (https link). Because I want to put it in 'image_url' in parameters and send it back to Facebook messenger API [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/generic-template). Do you have any idea? I know how to get value from json but this Google Places Photo returns something different. I know it won't return a json response.

Comment: I tried `print(str(resp))` and I get this back `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=200&photoreference=` & `CoQBcwAAAKoYnKhY40-G1p55pNqMnQrKGKpzD9_9abee8YUMO72VoWfl5CCAyI5iL3mU1BoUIXtlM1vOCar7ZpIRZAOjui5ByS70Ha7VN1z9Y8446xUxu_8PSgb5VaoxtlzXxTO63fC6dFZzEeX8R5Aos1ucVn0-yUbZxuLYgx6uLOopj1jWEhAZ9e6FBFOvWcXTQ51qp_LxGhRbJT1D6CCmaTIlpZvABh5QhXn8dQ`. The long string is the photo_reference, I checked it on browser and it returns `https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-es-54JIkYqQ/VvcJjK4fJbI/AAAAAAASeZE/T4whpXc9rDsjsk1tjOG3nmLqYATo2zcVw/s1600-w200/`